# EmbeddedZookeeper shutdown can't be done in windows

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka

The problem is nicely described in ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6291#

I wonder if someone has solution for the problem as it seems rather popular.